# bash: /usr/bin/groups: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: boot

by i  use this command `sudo rm /bin/sh` after that I rebooted my system and `tty` is open I entered my username and password after that   `bash: /usr/bin/groups: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` is showing I checked `/bin` directory `sh` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/dash` - so you should be able to fix your mistake by re-creating the link:

```
sudo ln -s dash /bin/sh
```

In future, don't randomly delete system files.